# What expressions/words are still used in Indian English that are no longer in British English?

Tags: british-english, dialects, subcontinental-english

I was traveling through India recently and noticed that many expressions that people used that I saw were somewhat older expressions, now disused in Standard English. Examples of these were:

> Please do the needful
>   Out of station
>   HORN OK Please

– and a few others. I also saw a sign that said:

> Please do not pluck the flowers.

Now I've heard of colonial lag and it seems that these are phrases that have fallen into disuse in the English language used in the west. I wanted to ask if there are other Indian English words/phrases that have retained their original meaning, but have fallen into disuse in (if I may, for said purposes) 'western English'?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding some formatting to your question. Your example sentences were a bit hard to figure out, though, so you should check that I've separated them correctly.

Comment: I was in India a few months ago (for the first time), and I saw `HORN OK Please` on a lot of trucks. After you've driven on a few Indian roads (or, better yet, had someone else drive you, as I did), you'll understand that it means "Please honk your horn before you try to pass me, so I'll know you're trying."

Comment: Are you sure these are archaic phrases, and not some kind of Hindi-English creole?

Comment: Barmar, that's a good question. I've never heard of anyone *pluck* flowers in England and the rest of the UK. People only *pick* them. The first three examples are peculiar and unheard of, in the UK.

Comment: Plucking flowers and someone being 'outstation' (thus written) is common in Malaysia and Singapore. I would imagine they will also be known in Sri Lanka.